# Form data in Codeigniter sent via AJAX to a Controller function that queries a database and returns an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a view called `mapsView` that contains a map which is generated in a controller function called `maps()`. In this view I also have a radio button form which is used to filter the markers on the map.

The form is sent via jquery and ajax to another controller function called `get_markers()` which queries the database successfully and returns an array of values including lng, lat and name which I need to pass back to my view.

The array is called `markerDetails` and when I do a `var_dump($query->result());` I can see that my query was a success.

I am new to using Codeigniter and the problem I have is caused because the form handling and database query are done in a separate controller function to the one that loads the map view. The `maps()` function creates the maps and `get_markers()`deals with the database query based on the form data submitted from the `mapsView` page.

I have tried moving all the code from the `get_markers()` controller function into the  `maps()` controller function but when I do the `var_dump($query->result());` returns everything in the table and not just the results of my query.

My main problem is that I need the results from my database query in the `mapsView` page but I cant reload the page because I will lose all the settings for my map.

The form is on the mapView page and is a standard radio button form with a hidden field that has a value for the location. on submit the form passes a value for the location and also for a type that has been picked via the radio buttons.

I am unsure how to approach this problem because the MVC method of doing things is new to me and am wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you please provide code?

Comment: Hi Bonik - I have narrowed down my problem to passing variables from one controller method to another without using a redirect. The view is loaded from controller method one and has variables that I need to maintain. Controller method two contains variables supplied through a form that I need to pass to controller method one without a redirect and from there access them in the view.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you need to pass data retrieved in a Model to a View.

I implement this by keeping data retrieved from Model in an array and and pass it to view as follows

In controller

```
function map(){
     $this->load->model('maps');
     $data['marker_details']=$this->maps->get_marker_details();
     $this->load->view('map_view',$data);
   }
```

The data passed would be received as a new variable eg $data['abc'] in controller could be accessed as $abc in view

Thus all your markers could be accessed as $marker_details in map_view

Hope this was needed